# Will this code create a latch?

Tags: verilog

Will that create a latch?

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
 if (enable) begin
   myvar1[63:0] <= some value;
   myvar2[63:0] <=some value2;
   myvar3[63:0] <= value3;
 end else begin
    myvar1[63:0] <=othervalue
 end
end
```

Should everything that is on the if, be on the else clause as well? I have understood that leaving an if without an else can cause a latch, but does it also mean that every signal on the if should be on the else?
If that's the case, should I write something like this:

```
myvar2[63:0] <= myvar2[63:0];
```

or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this code should not infer latches. It is the case in all the synthesizers that I saw.

The reason is that a synthesis tool will infer flip-flop for any signal which is assigned inside a sequential block of code (`@(posedge clk)`). For all the branches which do not have an explicit assignments, the synthesis tool just muxes the output to the input, but since it is initially a flop, there is no concern.

What you're saying about latches applies to conbinational logic. For example, the following code infers latches for both `myvar2` and `myvar3`:

```
always @* begin
 if (enable) begin
   myvar1[63:0] = some value;
   myvar2[63:0] =some value2;
   myvar3[63:0] = value3;
 end else begin
    myvar1[63:0] =othervalue
 end
end
```

Synthesis tries to mux the output to the input, but this requires a "memory" element to be in place in order to prevent a "loop". Latches controlled by `enable` signal will be inferred.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There's no concern about the contents of your `else` clause, because you've already created latches (registers) for all of those signals anyway, by putting them in a process that's triggered on a clock edge.

Comment: I think OP is using the term *latch* to mean a level-sensitive latch, as opposed to an edge-triggered flip-flop.

Comment: @ThePhoton: In that case, it would have to be an `always @*` block.

Comment: There's a lot of material out there that says "if you don't set all the same reg's in the else clause as you set in the if clause, it might infer a latch." Without explaining that distinction. I think that is what OP is asking about.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I think you're reading too much into the question. Vasiliy said the same thing I did, but in more detail, and the OP seemed happy with that answer.